# Get Value of last non-empty column for each row

Tags: r, string, dplyr

Take this sample data:

```
data.frame(a_1=c("Apple","Grapes","Melon","Peach"),a_2=c("Nuts","Kiwi","Lime","Honey"),a_3=c("Plum","Apple",NA,NA),a_4=c("Cucumber",NA,NA,NA)) 

   a_1    a_2   a_3     a_4
1  Apple  Nuts  Plum    Cucumber
2 Grapes  Kiwi  Apple    <NA>
3  Melon  Lime  <NA>     <NA>
4  Peach  Honey  <NA>    <NA>
```

Basically I want to run a grep on the last column of each row which is not NA. Thus my x in grep("pattern",x) should be:

```
Cucumber
Apple
Lime
Honey
```

I have an integer which tells me which a_N is the last one:

```
numcol <- rowSums(!is.na(df[,grep("(^a_)\\d", colnames(df))]))
```

So far I have tried something like this in combination with ave(), apply() and dplyr:

```
grepl("pattern",df[,sprintf("a_%i",numcol)])
```

However I dont quite can make it work. Keep in mind that my dataset is very large thus I was hoping vor a vectorized solution or mb dplyr. 
Help would be greatly appreciated.

/e: Thanks, that is a really good solution. My thinking was too complicated. (the regex is due to my more specific data )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no need for regex here. Just use `apply` + `tail` + `na.omit`:

```
> apply(mydf, 1, function(x) tail(na.omit(x), 1))
[1] "Cucumber" "Apple"    "Lime"     "Honey"
```

---

<s>I don't know how this compares in terms of speed, but you</s> You can also use a combination of "data.table" and "reshape2", like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
na.omit(melt(as.data.table(mydf, keep.rownames = TRUE), 
             id.vars = "rn"))[, value[.N], by = rn]
#    rn       V1
# 1:  1 Cucumber
# 2:  2    Apple
# 3:  3     Lime
# 4:  4    Honey
```

Or, even better:

```
melt(as.data.table(df, keep.rownames = TRUE), 
     id.vars = "rn", na.rm = TRUE)[, value[.N], by = rn]
#    rn       V1
# 1:  1 Cucumber
# 2:  2    Apple
# 3:  3     Lime
# 4:  4    Honey
```

This would be *much* faster. On an 800k-row dataset, `apply` took ~ 50 seconds while the `data.table` approach took about 2.5 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative that might be pretty fast:

```
DF[cbind(seq_len(nrow(DF)), max.col(!is.na(DF), "last"))]
#[1] "Cucumber" "Apple"    "Lime"     "Honey"
```

Where "DF":

```
DF = structure(list(a_1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Apple", "Grapes", 
"Melon", "Peach"), class = "factor"), a_2 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("Honey", "Kiwi", "Lime", "Nuts"), class = "factor"), 
    a_3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("Apple", "Plum"
    ), class = "factor"), a_4 = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "Cucumber", class = "factor")), .Names = c("a_1", 
"a_2", "a_3", "a_4"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try: (`df1` is the dataset)

```
 indx <- which(!is.na(df1), arr.ind=TRUE)
 df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1),tapply(indx[,2], indx[,1], FUN=max))]
 #[1] "Cucumber" "Apple"    "Lime"     "Honey"
```